# Yii, CDbTestCase save() fails

Tags: activerecord, yii, phpunit

I want to test the creation of a group in my application. So I copied the AR-Test of the tutorial and modified it to my needs. I added a fixture and if I call ...::model()->findAll() I get the groups of the fixture.

In my test I want to create a new group und verify, that the group was inserted. $this->assertTrue($group->save()) passes but var_dump($group->id) is NULL.
Here my test:

```
public function testCreateGroup(){
    // Insert new group
    $group= RightGroup::model();
    $group->title = 'Create Test';
    $this->assertTrue($group->save());

    // Verify created and updated date
    $group = RightGroup::model()->findByPk($group->id);
    $this->assertTrue($group instanceof RightGroup);
}
```

And here is my model. It is autogenerated and edited by myself.

```
class RightGroup extends CActiveRecord {

// Constants
const ADMIN_GROUP = 1;
const USER_GROUP = 2;

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return RightGroup the static model class
 */
public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName() {
    return 'right_groups';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('title', 'required'),
        array('title', 'length', 'max' => 50),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, title, created, updated', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        // Set the updated value for each update
        array('updated', 'default', 'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'), 'setOnEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'update'),
        // Set the created and updated values at create action
        array('created,updated', 'default', 'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'), 'setOnEmpty' => false, 'on' => 'insert')
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'right_group_users(group_id, user_id)'),
        'rights' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Right', 'right_groups_rights(group_id, right_id)'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'id' => Yii::t('right','ID'),
        'title' => Yii::t('right','Title'),
        'created' => Yii::t('right','Created'),
        'updated' => Yii::t('right','Updated'),
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search() {
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id, true);
    $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
    $criteria->compare('created', $this->created, true);
    $criteria->compare('updated', $this->updated, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Proofs if the given right belongs to this right group.
 * 
 * @param Right $right
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasRight(Right $right) {
    return in_array($right, $this->rights);
}

public function behaviors() {
    return array('CAdvancedArBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.CAdvancedArBehavior'));
}

}
```

Where is my bug?

Comment: Are you sure your column is marked as Auto Increment in your db structure?

Comment: Yes, it is a MySQL table and the column id is Auto_Increment

Comment: That's weird. What about your RightGroup model. Is it a generated model or did you edit it? If so, please post it.

Comment: Weird stuff. Are you sure about AI? Did you double check? Got any triggers in your db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not craete a new group with `$group = new Group::model()` but `$group = new Group`.